# Does it make sense to use NextJS and CRA together?

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

I'm building an application that is using NextJS to handle stuff that should be SSRed like landing, FAQ, blog pages. I also have an API for the **application** itself to interact with. Emphasis on **application**, since the pages NextJS is rendering isn't necessarily the actual **application**.

My question is would it be ideal to set up Webpack, Babel, etc for the actual **application** since it would be a gated application resulting in it not benefiting from being SSRed like the front-facing pages?

Comment: No, you can not use `next.js` and `CRA` together, if you want to disable ssr then follow this https://dev.to/apkoponen/how-to-disable-server-side-rendering-ssr-in-next-js-1563

Comment: No it does not make any sense

Comment: take a look at [react-snap](https://github.com/stereobooster/react-snap)

Comment: react-snap looks interesting - but it feels like avoiding NextJS. I guess for an existing CRA project that is too late to start again using NextJS @Mhmdrz_A